# fargate cloudwatch cpu utilization percentile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I've created dashboard for a service deployed to Fargate using the following:

```
Namespace
AWS/ECS
Metric name
CPUUtilization
```

Both `Average` and `Max` can be viewed but neither of these is that useful.  `Max` is really high and `Average` is really low.

When choosing `p99` from the drop-down selector no data is returned and nothing is plotted on the chart.  Is it just a case that p99 isn't supported by `CPUUtilization` metric on Fargate?

Is there a way to get this stat manually on the dashboard, and added to an Alarm as a threshold?

Comment: If I'm understanding this [AWS stats definitions page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Percentiles) correctly, `p99` is not available for Fargate.  If this is the case then what function should be used to interpret and alarm on CPU/Mem etc?

Comment: Using Fargate Container Insights shows CPUUtilization in units and the p99 selector can be selected and data plotted on the chart.  However, the y-axis doesn't show a percentage.  How can this be interpreted?

Comment: Based on the definitions page I'd interpret that as a bug tbh. Sounds like you shouldn't be able to select p99 on that page

Comment: Good point @Fermin.  Do you know what the best function to use is to monitor and alert CPU Utilisation?

Comment: use use CPUUtilization Average and it works okay for me. If you navigate to ECS console -> <service> -> "Health and metrics" tab there is a CPU Utilization graph. Expanding that then selecting "View in metrics" shows that it plots CPUUtilization Maximum/Minimum/Average over a 5min period. Is your period too large so it's averaging out low?

Comment: Yes using Avergage seems like the only option now.  When the period is 1 minute, the Average and Max show the values on the graph.  I guess the period of 1 minute shows a single value?